# Проблемное регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида:
 = + + +...; = + + +...;

Надо выделить сколько подстрок вида "=+++...;". Т.е. пробелы не учитываем, первый символ "=" , далее от одного до без разницы сколько "+", а завершает это все символ ";".

Работает:

```
/[\+]{1,}/mx
```

Но как только хочу подставить = или ; перестает работать. Т.е.

```
/=[\+]{1,};/mx
```

к сожалению не срабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а зачем здесь вообще регулярки ?

```
$new = array();
$lists = explode(';', $str);
foreach ($lists as $l) {
    $l = trim($l);
    if (substr($l, 0, 1) != '=') continue;
    $new[] = substr($l, 1);
}
```

зы: в один проход вы не заматчите отдельно сколько угодно таких комбинаций.
если все же хочется регуляркой то

```
if (preg_match_all('~\=([\+\s]+);~', $str, $m)) {
    print_r($m);
}
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения лучше подходят задаче, по идее. Как-никак (PHP, вроде, libpcre использует), их должно скомпилировать в достаточно эффективный автомат, который шустро один раз пробежит по строке и все.

Кстати, Ваш пример с циклом, кстати, плюсы вообще игнорирует, и радостно примет и «`= +++ ;`» и «`= abc ;`».

Comment: Спасибо. Это выражение работает! Только пару часов изучаю регулярки)) И на этом последнем моменте застрял на долго...

П.С. Это лаба по проектированию лексического анализатора через регулярные выражения. Без них никак) Без них делал в предыдущей)

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что дело в пробелах.

Если так, то, возможно, поможет `/=[+\s]+;/m`

(`{1,}` это то же самое, что и `+`; а в `[...]` плюс, вроде бы, можно не экранировать.)

Comment: нет. троеточие в конце - это неограниченное количество плюсов)

Comment: Не-не-не, я про то, что `/A{1,}/` и /A+/ это одно и то же, и найдет `A`, `AAA` и `AAAAAA`. Просто вместо `{1,}` можно написать `+`.

Comment: А-а-а! Спасибо. Буду знать)